# GWT + symfony2, am I crazy?

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, symfony, seo

Does anyone has experience on integrating GWT and Symfony2?
Currently I'm using Symfony2 with the frontend being JQuery + HTML.
Writing Javascript drives me crazy although JQuery has already been used.

I'd like to know if there are any successful cases? GWT can generates javascript for me.
I only need to write type-safe and OO Java.

But, there is another concern, with GWT normal practice, the HTML elements are all created dynamically. So when a page is being crawled by the search engine, there are no elements for it to crawl. Is it a serious problem affecting the SEO rank?

Comment: One point to add, I don't want to use GWT entirely with Java as the backend, I still want to keep PHP as the backend language to ensure the performance.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is a powerful tool you can write your code in java and GWT will generate Cross browser supported JavaScript.

Dynamic pages are created on the fly. These pages function well for users who visit the site, but they don’t work well for search engine crawlers.

Why? Because dynamically generated pages don’t actually exist until a user selects the variable that generate them. A search engine spider can’t select variables, so the pages don’t get generated  and can’t be indexed. There are different strategies available for reference check [Dynamic sites SEO tips](http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamic-site-seo-tips-hints/)

Comment: sorry, how do you define "dynamically generated pages"?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the SEO tips. That only gives me part of the information. What I'm worried is that with GWT, all HTML elements are generated in the client-side JS. So the page generated by the server side will be a very simple page with only a <body></body>. This kind of page is not possible to be crawled and indexed. I know that we can do data-binding with GWT, but it seems to be even more crazy to have Symfony2/TWIG generates the HTML, and then GWT bind JS events on it... Anybody really did this? or anyone using Symfony2 just tolerates using traditional JS?